# XML Parse in website

Tags: java, android, xml, parsexml

I'm trying parse a webpage in XML and print data in my logcat, but my output is empty.
This is my XML structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<FLIGHTS>
    <FLIGHT airport="b: 3  "
        logo="IG"
        code="IG"
        numero="1234" 
        carrier="AirBerlin"
        city="NEW YORK"
        terminal="Terminal A"
        sched="08:40"
        expect="09:09" 
        tipo_volo="L" stato="J"
    </FLIGHT>
    <FLIGHT airport="c: 3  "
     ....
     .....more...
    </FLIGHT>
</FLIGHTS>
```

and this is my Android code inside AsyncTask:

```
     @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {


            URL url = new URL("http://myurl");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("FLIGHT");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
              // NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("airport");
               // Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
           //     a.add(line.getTextContent());

                Log.d("LOG...", "" + element.getTextContent());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

inside the AndroidManifest, i have the internet permission!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample works. Java is case sensitive. Are you sure your XML tag name is correct?

Here is a working example using a XML example of w3schools:

```
  try {

         URL url = new URL("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml");
         URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

         DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

         NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("note");
         for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            // NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("airport");
            // Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
            // a.add(line.getTextContent());

            System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

And now using your XML example and [Joop Eggen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen) answer:

```
try {

     URL url = new URL("http://myurl");
     URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

     NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("FLIGHT");
     for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        String airport = element.getAttribute("airport");

        System.out.println("element " + i + ": airport=" + airport);
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Example using a simple file:

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FLIGHTS>
    <FLIGHT airport="b: 3  " logo="IG" code="IG" numero="1234"
        carrier="AirBerlin" city="NEW YORK" terminal="Terminal A" sched="08:40"
        expect="09:09" tipo_volo="L" stato="J">
    </FLIGHT>
</FLIGHTS>
```

Example.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("test.xml");
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(f));

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("FLIGHT");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        String airport = element.getAttribute("airport");

        System.out.println("element " + i + ": airport='" + airport + "'");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I think I see the problem: Try doc.getElementsByName("FLIGHTS") and not only "FLIGHT". This will list all FLIGHT nodes.

Comment: That code sample only "works" if the XML was proper XML. Look at the XML in the question again

Comment: Ok, if the XML really looks like the example it cannot work, indeed. But I think the data comes from some public api? <FLIGHT someAttribute="text" anotherAttribute="text2"></FLIGHT>

Comment: Perhaps, but there aren't equal signs in XML elements is all I'm saying

Comment: You mean like XML attributes? Sure there are equal signs! http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

Comment: So getAttribute should be used instead, as the other answer has

Comment: Thank you.. I 'm Try. My url finish with page.php but if i see the source code, i have the pure XML.  Work for me?

Comment: It should work. Did you try my second code sample? It should print out the airport value of every FLIGHT tag.

Comment: I have changed FLIGHTS to FLIGHT and it work! but there is a problem.. i can see only: b:   ........ <FLIGHT airport="b: 3  " i can't see number 3. 02-08 00:24:11.768 11438-11458/? I/System.out: element 1: airport= b:

Comment: I have edited the answer providing a working example using an XML file instead of the URL. It works and prints out: element 0: airport='b: 3  '. If it does not work I would check the XML. Is it valid? You can check it here: https://validator.w3.org/check

Answer (score 1):

If the XML were correct, attributes `XXX="..."` are got differently:

```
Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
String airport = element.getAttribute("airport");
if (airport != null) { ...
```